# using documentMode with typescript

Tags: typescript

I check if the browser is ie by:

```
function isBrowserIE() {
  return window.document.documentMode;
}
```

Typescript raises an error:

> Error TS2339: Property 'documentMode' does not exist on type 'Document'.

This is due to the [change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes) made in typescript compiler at version 1.5 :

> Properties documentMode, parentWindow, createEventObject are removed from type Document

How can i get rid from the error?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. any luck

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply add it to the `Document` interface:

```
interface Document {
    documentMode?: any;
}

function isBrowserIE() {
    return window.document.documentMode;
}
```

---

#### Edit

If you are using modules then you need to use [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation):

```
declare global {
    interface Document {
        documentMode?: any;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Do you have the `interface Document` code in the same file in which you're trying to use the `documentMode` property?

Comment: yes,

export interface Document {
    documentMode?: any;
}

export class StateHistoryService {
      private detectIE() {
        return !!this.win.document.documentMode;
    }

}

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Check my revised answer

Comment: Using `documentMode?: number` rather than `documentMode?: any` is safer, as it disallows `document.documentMode.toString()` or `document.documentMode?.arbitraryPropName` (while still allowing `document.documentMode?.toString()`).

Answer (score 24):

I've used bracket notation to get rid of the error:
    `document['documentMode']`

Comment: this. TS validation can be really pedantic

Comment: The good old trick worked here. Thank you for pointing this out :)

Comment: TS : object access via string literals is disallowed (no-string-literal)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `@ts-ignore` since I know that `document.documentMode` will never cause a problem when it's compiled.

```js
// @ts-ignore
var isIE = !!document.documentMode;
```